# if block not evaluating as expected

Tags: python

```
answer == raw_input("Do you like python?")
if answer == "yes":
      print "That is great"
elif answer == "no"
      print "that is disappointing"
else:
      print "that is not the answer to my question"
```

The problem with this code is that python 2.7.2 ignores my first two conditions, but responds to the last one. Why is this? I am about two and half weeks new into learning python and I have been looking for other resources. Here is the reference to where I originally got the info from http://www.upriss.org.uk/python/PythonCourse.html

Comment: The example at the bottom of http://www.upriss.org.uk/python/session2.html shows `answer = raw_input(...)` with a single `=` just like the answers here. Did you make an error retyping the example?

Comment: -1: What a terrible question title.  Is it possible to fix the title to describe the actual question?

Answer (score 11):

You're using `==` instead of `=` in the first line of code. As far as the code you've shown, `answer` is never actually assigned a value.

Oh, and there's a missing colon in the line `elif answer == "no"`.

---

Here, have a cookie:

```
answer = raw_input("Do you like python?")
if answer == "yes":
    print "That is great"
elif answer == "no":
    print "that is disappointing"
else:
    print "that is not the answer to my question"
```

Comment: Still pretty much at a standstill and its still ignoring my first two coditions and is only fulfilling the last one. I put the missing colons and i assigned the value for 'answer'. What do you suggest that I try next.

Comment: I don't want to sound unsympathetic but I honestly don't understand how this is possible, _assuming that you have updated your original buggy code_ based on the suggestions you have received here. Look, here's proof that it works: http://ideone.com/rH1kL. I don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Matt Ball's answer, but a little more detailed (considering the asker):

There is a significant difference in Python between "=" and "=="

"=" is used to assign a value to a variable, as seen in the following.

```
my_variable = "value"
```

"==" is used to compare two values.

```
if my_variable == "value"
```

Of course, a variable must have a value before you can check that value! Otherwise, its like sending your secretary after the contents of an empty envelope.

It is VERY easy to confuse "=" and "==", so don't feel bad. My first code in Python looked like spaghetti. :P

Best wishes to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = raw_input("Do you like Python?")
if answer.lower() in ("yes", "y"):
    print "That is great."
elif answer.lower() in ("no", "n"):
    print "That is disappointing."
else:
    print "That is not the answer to my question."
```

Comment: You have enhanced the code rather than pointing out what it was that was wrong with it. While you have fixed the defect incidentally, you haven't explained what it was. His question was why it was failing--not how it could be extended.

Comment: I'm sure he could see the difference. If you want to waste points downvoting senselessly, have at it.

Comment: This helps me because it teaches me something new, so I have a couple of questions. What does "lower" mean? Also, why is the "n" and "y" emphazied after yes and no.

Comment: Tyler - went ahead and upvoted you to get rid of the minus vote.  Your answer is good, and the down vote was unnecessary and rude.

Comment: The answer.lower() is necessary to make sure that no matter the case the user types in, your program will catch it becuase it converts it all to lower case.  Basically the string "Yes" is not the same as "yes" but converting it to lower case gets rid of any issues you have.  The "y" and "n" were added to allow the user to type in "y" or "n" instead of "yes" or "no".

Comment: @Lance, I am glad to know that some people have some since. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo, normally I answer the question and that's it. Since you are new, I figured I would show you a thing or two.

Comment: humph, the same problem is occuring with another code that I wrote it is similar to the last problem, in which python would only run part of my script even though I think that I have most of it right.

Comment: Wow, misspelled sense. Anyway, @Ricardo, start a new question if it's a new problem.